# Transfer BIM360 folders from one Hub to another

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management, autodesk-bim360

is it possible to transfer files/folders "Hub A" to "Hub B"? Let's say we use Hub A (and C4R) for prototyping purposes, and every month we have to download this prototypes, which is problematic because either the download does not have a directory structure or BIM 360 just never finishes "compressing your items". After downloading and matching the folder structure, we upload this files again to Hub B every time there is a major update to the prototypes.

There is a way to copy files using BIM 360 UI, but just within the same hub.

I would appreciate some guidance here. I've just done some step by step tutorials to get the viewer on my website, so I do not have much experience.

Thanks,

Xavier

Answer (score 0):

Since you ask this question with “Forge Data Management API” tag, so I assume you want to implement the way to achieve that by API.

With the current Data Management API, there is not an easy API to do that directly, but if you want to transfer files/folders from "Hub A" to "Hub B", you can always check & download all the files/folder from "Hub A", and then upload them to "Hub B". There are many details you may need to handle, for example, when the file you want to upload is already there, you can either create a new version or just override it.

We have some similar samples may help you to understand or get started with if you are interested. For example, https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/data.management-nodejs-integration.box , this is used to exchange files between "Autodesk Hub" and "Box", you can download and check. Also, https://github.com/Developer-Autodesk/data.management-csharp-a360sync , this sample is used to sync the files from local to your A360 account, it's a C# desktop application and is still working in progress as mentioned in README, but, you can get the idea from sample/code anyway.

Hope it helps.